# What's diamond's melting point?

Tags: energy

I've been looking around but I've found no clear answer. The most I could find was: "around 4000K"

Has it not been determined and it's just an estimation?

Comment: Then you haven't seen [this answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8590/what-is-the-melting-point-of-diamond) over on Chemistry.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks a question answered at Chemistry SE.

Comment: @Void: While I do not consider this a *good* question, it does not follow from the on-topic character of a question on another SE site that it must be off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon [has no melting point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon#Characteristics) at ordinary atmospheric pressures (around $0.1\,\mathrm{MPa}$)- it will sublime directly into gaseous form. Below pressures of around $10\,\mathrm{MPa}$, there is no way that carbon could exist as a liquid.

Comment: Another point to make: it is extremely hard to measure this accurately, and properties of diamonds large enough to measure (which are often naturally grown) vary quite a bit. And just imagine the look of your boss when you say "I would like to buy a large diamond so I can melt it because science." Most people are happy with a bit of uncertainty in these situations.